# Close popup after a time

Tags: settimeout

I use this code to show my popup automatically and I want to know how to close it automatically after 5 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

});
```

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if you feel it answers your question. You are under no obligation, however.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying an example from [Mozilla's developer page on WindowTimers.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout), call this function from within your existing document.ready function:

```
delayedAlertClose();
```

Add these functions outside your document.ready function:

```
function delayedAlertClose() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(popupClose, 5000);
}

function popupClose() {
    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
}
```